# Map not showing behind polygon

Tags: postgis, postgresql, sql, mapbox

I have inserted polygon data in POSTGIS using an SQL query via dbeaver. However, when I view the value tab, only the polygon is showing without the map whereas when I am seeing Multipolygon in the value tab, the polygon with map is appearing.

PS : The value of Multipolygon is not inserted by me.

```
INSERT INTO spatial (id,geometry)
VALUES (106,
    ST_GeomFromGeoJSON(
        '{
    "type":"Polygon",
    "coordinates":
    [
        [
            [ 537414.977755326661281, 9236064.317214528098702 ], [ 537137.774410196230747, 9236063.656908333301544 ],.....
        ]
    ],
    "crs":{"type":"name","properties":{"name":"EPSG:3857"}}
}'
    )
)
```

[image: Polygon image without map]

[image: Multipolygon image with map in background]

So now I have made a Python script and inserted Polygons and Multipolygons in the same column but am still unable to view the map in background.
Here is the code.

```
with open("a.txt") as input_file:
    data = json.load(input_file)
    count = 0
    count1=0
    for feature in data["features"]:
        props = feature["properties"]
        geo= feature["geometry"]
        print(geo['type'])

        if(geo['type']=='Polygon'):
            geom=(geo['coordinates'])
            # name=(props['Ward_Name'])
            name='test'
            print(geom)
            dataa = {'type':'Polygon',"coordinates": geom}

            cursor.execute("""INSERT INTO mypolygons (name,geom_p_mp)  VALUES (%s,ST_SetSRID(ST_GeomFromGeoJSON(%s),3857))""",
                           (name,json.dumps(dataa),))
            count+=1
            print(count)
        elif(geo['type']=='MultiPolygon'):
            geom_m = (geo['coordinates'])
            dataa_m = {"type": "MultiPolygon",
                     "coordinates": geom_m}
            # name=(props['Ward_Name'])
            name='testp'

            cursor.execute(
                """INSERT INTO mypolygons (name,geom_p_mp)  VALUES (%s,ST_SetSRID(ST_GeomFromGeoJSON(%s),3857))""",
                (name, json.dumps(dataa_m),))
```

[image: Database]

I am inserting in geom_p_mp

[image: Column Data Type]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can manually set the viewer CRS. If it is not registered in the column (or geometry?) it may fallback on the default 4326

[image]

Comment: Could you please look into the edited question?

Comment: The coordinates you have provided in 3857 are over the ocean and the Open Street Map basemap shows an ocean-blue background, it looks fine.